# 64-bit Support in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder

I'm looking at upgrading the Borland/Codegear/Embarcadero C++ builder suite we use for some of our code.  I would like to see 64-bit support but that doesn't seem to be a feature in the 2009 edition.  I swear I saw a roadmap suggesting that there would be a new release in mid-2009 which would include x64, but now that document is lost to me.  Does anybody know of a release schedule or a roadmap for Commodore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone seems to refer to the same link, http://dn.codegear.com/article/36620. But right now, there's nothing there. Everyone who talks about what was supposedly at that address mentions 64-bit support coming in 2009 Q2. So you're remembering correctly. But the original source is unavailable from Embarcadero.

It's available via [Google's cache](http://dn.codegear.com/article/36620), though. It places the release of "Commodore" in the "middle of 2009" with features including cross-compilation targeting native 64-bit code from a 32-bit IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Embarcadero has just released a new roadmap for C++Builder for 2012:

[Coming soon to a RAD IDE near you, the future of C++ - 64bit, C++11, ARM, iOS and Android](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/42275)

Answer (score 2):

I see there is now a new "RAD Studio, Delphi and C++Builder Roadmap", posted [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934) in August 2010, which says "Projected availability 1st half 2011".

UPDATE: in [David Intersimone's blog](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2011/09/02/41169) in September 2011, he answered the question "what about c++ builder 64 bit? is it discontinued?" with "We are working on a next generation new C++Builder compiler. This will allow us to get to 64-bit and ARM chips. The compiler is still being built so it could not make XE2. It is on our roadmap and we’ll have it for you." 
Elsewhere I have seen that this is predicted (by Embarcadero) to appear in XE3.

Answer (score 1):

64 Bit support for Delphi and C++ (C++ builder) is available in RAD Studio XE2 which is due for release very soon.

[Look at the link for the RAD Studio XE2 events](http://now.eloqua.com/es.asp?s=608&e=441997&elq=4118dee3c26b407dac6f3abdeeee43cd)

Comment: There is no 64-bit for C++Builder in XE2.

Answer (score 1):

XE2 has been released but I don't see anything about 64 bit support for C++ Builder, only Delphi.

Comment: That is because C++ support for 64-bit has not been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

I asked David Intersimone about BCC64 in his blog which commented by dear JV. It seems the 64bit bcc is imminent.

Answer (score 1):

C++ Builder 64bit support will be released in Q4 2012. However, C++ Builder XE3 has been released and there was a promo to get the 64bit beta support if you bought support service at the same time.

The information I got from the XE3 Road tour was that they still don't know if the 64bit will be considered a "major" upgrade or not. Meaning that if you buy XE3 now you have to buy an upgrade (again) to get the 64bit in Q4. If it isn't a "major" upgrade you will get it for free.

I was going to upgrade my XE2 to an XE3 but I'm waiting for the official 64bit release instead. If I have waited **several years** for the 64bit support, I can wait a few more month...

Comment: Fortunately I have long since moved on from that job. I have no idea what they did about the lack of 64 bit support, I'll ask.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/259-codegear-puts-64-bit-on-the-roadmap.html) talks about Commodore (Delphi) coming in Winter 2008 with 64-bit support.
  It mentions Delphi Tiburon (due 2009) which has extra features which is followed by C++ with those same features (and hopefully 64-bit support).

However the 'Borland' article that it links to has disappeared so I guess all bets are off.

Seriously, I don't believe there's any room in the IDE space for two costed products. I think Visual Studio will always be the costed product of choice with everyone else choosing a free solution such as Eclipse CDT or bare-bones GCC.

I think the Borland products were wonderful for their time (exceeded only by the TopSpeed/JPI compilers and putting Microsoft's early efforts to shame) but they've done their dash and are now relegated to the museum (my opinion only, I've been wrong before, and other various disclaimers).

Comment: The blog post says Tiburón was due in 2008, not 2009, and indeed it was, a few months ago, as Delphi 2009. That article is quite outdated, and also inaccurate.

Comment: So it was. I didn't actually note the date on the article.